# Can you have an <iframe> tag with no spaces?

Tags: xss, javascript, html, iframe

I am looking to figure out how to create an iFrame tag without any spaces.  I have found an input on a Bug Bounty program that reflects my input back into the page, and allows me to escape double quotes and an angle bracket. The page has XSS protection so my next thought would be iFrame injection. With that said, sadly, because of where my RXSS is located in the document, I can't include a space anywhere in my payload.

`<iframe src="\\12341234">`

It also doesn't allow periods or forward slashes but I found a way around that. All I need to figure out, is how to replace that space (in between iframe and src). Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: What about CR or LF?

Comment: Other white-spaces like %09(TAB) are often a possible replacement for spaces too, apart from CR/LF like @Marcel said

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, but this should work `<iframe/src=//14.rs>`. If anything still not allows so, try some encoding or else find out the js files from the page source and please share the relevant code so it will help to analyze what exactly happening.

Comment: +1 that's a good solution if OPs way of bypassing the `/` filter allows for it. Otherwise, [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/47684/what-is-a-good-xss-vector-without-forward-slashes-and-spaces) may also work.

Comment: As per my understanding, he is in HTML now, so I think mostly HTML tags will work, `<script\src=*> ` from your reference might not work as he mentioned that javascript would not be injected cause of some protection. also, this payload will need // ( forward slashed to give any malicious script link ). It would be better and easy to understand if we got to see the source and what is happening behind the page. other than this, bypassing encoding is the better option.